# Error checking in Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am getting a an object from my API call, i am trying to do an error checking before rendering the JSON data to my view.

```
function response(oResponse) {
        if(oResponse && oResponse!= null 
              && typeof oResponse === "object" &&  oResponse.responseCode !== null){
              // you're getting data in JSON
              // Use responseCode to proceed further
        }
}
```

Below is my `JSON` response

```
{"code": "100", "responseCode":"444", :result: "successful"}
```

I would like to know whether the `if condition` is right or not? Am i missing something in it or is it a big condition.

Comment: Can you post your AJAX call? You should have an Error: callback in your AJAX, that should handle all of it.

Comment: What are your requirements for validity? Tell us that and we can tell you if you are missing something.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: My requirement is to check whether the oResponse is present and oResponse.responseCode should be present before proceeding manipulating the data. I am just worried whether i am doing a lot of checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably simplify the condition to `oResponse && oResponse.responseCode` if all you care about is that it is not `null` nor `undefined`, and it has a `responseCode` property that is not `null` nor `undefined`.

- The check for `oResponse != null` is redundant since `null` evaluates to `false`.
- The check for `oResponse.responseCode !== null` is redundant for the same reason.
- The check for `typeof oResponse === "object"` is redundant since if it was a string or other type it wouldn't have a `responseCode` property.

Note that if `oResponse.responseCode === 0` or [another "falsy" value](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), this condition will evaluate to false (i.e., that is considered an "invalid" responseCode).

@snowYetis comment about an error handler is also a good idea to have in there in case there is an error on the server. It won't cover the validation of a successful response that is invalid though.

Comment: you mean to say if(oResponse && oResponse.responseCode) is more than enough to check for null and undefined, instead of the big lines. right?

Comment: Added a warning about falsy response codes. It should be "just enough", perhaps not "more than enough" :)

Comment: Ah haaa... i am sure the API won't return "0", but if it returns by any chance... how to handle that too... i guess this would be more than enough "if(oResponse && oResponse.responseCode)" right? I am sorry for asking again...

Comment: My inclination is usually to keep validation as simple as possible, then handle known bad values separately. For instance, keep `if (oResponse && oResponse.responseCode) {`, but add something like `if (oResponse.responseCode === 0) { ` within that block for those exceptional cases. That's kind of outside the realm of this particular question though. Feel free to ask another question and link to this one if you have more specific questions.