# My ajax code has a problem, and i don't know what can I do

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

That's the code. The problem is, when i press the button it doesn't do anything, and i want just to check if ajax works. I mean when i press the button to alert me with data..
This is index.php

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "jumbotron">
            <input type = "username" name = "username" id = "username" placeholder = "username">
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password" placeholder = "password">
            <button name = "startRegister" id = "startRegister">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#startRegister').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var user = $('#username').val();
            var pass = $('#password').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"register.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {username: user, password: pass},
                succes:function(data){
                 alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

This is register.php

```
<?php
 echo "Welcome to first php !";
?>
```

IMAGE WITH MY FILES:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcQxa.png)

Comment: how is this related to php?

Comment: there are too many possible reasons here and we don't know how you're using this, if on a personal computer or on a host somewhere. PHP requires a webserver to run on and PHP installed. For me, the question is unclear.

Comment: You can user the debugging tools in your browser to look at the request the ajax call is trying to make. I think for a start you will find that "register.php" is no a valid URL.

Comment: Look, I just want if my code works. I mean when i run the jquery with ajax to send me the alert. I work with xampp on localhost.

Comment: To add to what Jerry said; enable error reporting, and check your logs.

Comment: *succes* - This was about a typo all along? I'd like to change my vote from unclear to as a typo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error checking in Ajax Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400898/error-checking-in-ajax-response)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it doesn't do anything for you then you are probably not hitting that "**success**" trigger you are aiming for. It would be best to open up the Console (right click -> `Inspect` if you are using Google Chrome) and check for any messages there after you hit the button.

In the code you copied, you have "succes", while the trigger is actually "success" (double s)

Furthermore, you can extend the AJAX call to also do error handling:

```
 data: {username: user, password: pass},
 success:function(data){
      alert(data);
 },
 error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert(request.responseText);
 }
```

Comment: When i press the button it doesn't say anything, but it shows me 1 error: ERROR: Execution of script 'adblock' failed! Showtime is not defined

Comment: You should whitelist localhost in your AdBlock, after all its your own playground, nothing to block there :) Also, check my edit, I found a typo in your code causing this entire headache ;)